# How to extract planting lines from a raster image?

Tags: qgis, saga

I have a high quality drone image and I want to remove the soil and leave only the planting line.So far already able to classify the images leaving 1 for the plantations and 0 for the soil, it is a gray image of simple band, I made the separation using the NIR image and using r.reclass.

The difficulty is to crop the RGB image to display only the crops, I do not know how to do that.I tried to vectorize the reclassified image to trim the RBG but it did not work, it's still in the process of vectorizing, it's taking too long!I do not know if it is possible to remove RGB soil using the raster calculator.

Any suggestions are welcome. I currently use QGIS and SAGA.
Here is an image to illustrate.[image]

Comment: I'm not fully sure I understand what you need, but you could try multiplying your RGB image by the reclassed image in raster calculator. This would in effect convert all of the soil areas to raster values of 0 in the RGB image.

Comment: so you want the planting lines to show the original imagery colours where your classification is 'plantation', and everything else to be NODATA / transparent? you certainly don't want to go the vectorisation route if this is a high-res drone image. I think @jbukoski approach is right one and would encourage them to write up as an answer if that is what you're after :)

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you @jbukoski!
Exactly @StevenKay  , vectorizing is almost impossible, it would be a lot of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you did not mention GRASS in your question, here's a map calculator expression that, I believe, would give you what you want:

```
r.mapcalc "planting_lines = if(nir_reclass == 1, rgb, null() )
```